# Which is better API design for POST endpoints?

Tags: rest, api

I want to create an endpoint for posting different types of commands. I have the option to have one route /commands which can be used for every command type or one route for each command i.e. /commands/commandA, /commands/commandB etc.

Which one of these approaches is favourable or is it a "it depends" case? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: It's "it depends" like 99% of the time. An API design is approached from the business (strategy) standpoint. Think about security, accessibility, scalability, etc.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, especially since this RPC-style command approach wouldn't be "REST" anyway. But some practical concerns: do you want to use your web framework's "router" to map commands to pieces of code, or are you going to do routing/dispatch yourself? Using multiple routes is also potentially more debuggable, as you can tell from HTTP logs what commands are being invoked. That's something that I've dearly missed when working with `POST /graphql` style endpoints. On the other hand, having a single endpoint can be useful for doing batch operations (multiple commands in one request).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @amon in what way is it RPC style?

Comment: @Christian REST is built around resources upon which you perform operations such as `POST`.  Your proposed URI schemes represent actions.  There's no apparent resource.

Comment: @JimmyJames I see. Well the commands in this case are something that eventually represent an action in the real world but I would argue they're also resources in that they will be stored as such.

Comment: If I'm following, you are saying that this interface is allowing you to create a one or more commands that are stored and realized later?  I.e., from the perspective of the interface, they are nouns?  If so, that probably makes sense, it just wasn't what I initially understood from the question.

Comment: Can you clarify what 'commands' are in this setup. When you say you want to post to the commands what do you mean? What are you posting to them? Do you mean you want to execute them? For example if I did a HTTP request `GET /commands/command1` what would I expect to be returned? If I `PUT /commands/command1` what would I be changing the state of?

Comment: @CormacMulhall yes, a posted command will be executed with a certain set of properties that are specific for that command. `GET`ing a command would return the state of the command and the properties that the command was executed with.

Answer (score 2):

There many approaches to this with HTTP. I'm going to ignore the security aspect of remote execution of commands and just answer the question about the endpoints.

You could `POST` to your endpoint with a JSON request body containing the needed data for your command:

```
POST /exec

{ 
  bin: 'ls', 
  opts: ['-l', '-h'] 
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `GET` and query strings containing all data:

```
GET /exec?bin=ls&opts=[-l,-h]
```

Or, you could go for one route per command:

```
GET /exec/ls?opts=[-l,-h]
```

Remember to URL encode all query string values.